# ORB giving better feature matching than SIFT - why?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, sift, orb

I have rencently been trying to solve a problem using feature matching, utilizing the feature matching algorithms provided by the OpenCV libraries in C++.

Now there is one example where ORB gives me better matches than SIFT, what made me wonder. I thought ORB was an attempt to deliver comparable quality to SIFT while needing less coputation time. That's why I thought I might have done something wrong with my SIFT matching. However, with other images it works good.

The example I am talking about is a binary image.
Here is the result obtainted with SIFT:

[image]

And here is the result using ORB:

[image]

The first result was obtained with a SIFT feature detector and a SIFT descriptor extractor. For the matching I used the brute force matcher with the L2 norm. For the second one I used an ORB feature detector and an ORB descriptor extractor and also the brute force matcher but with the Hamming distance.

I filtered the matches in both cases by computing a homography with the RANSAC outlier filtering method and then only keeping the selected point pairs.

I tried to fiddled around with the parameters of the descriptor matcher, but the result didn't change much.

Now, do you think there is a plausible explanation for why ORB seems to perform better in this case? Is it maybe suited better for such a type of image? Or is there something wrong with the SIFT result?

Edit: Some code:

```
void KeypointMatcher::computeMatches(cv::Mat image1, cv::Mat image2, FeatureDetectorType detectorType, DescriptorExtractorType extractorType, DescriptorMatcherType matcherType) {
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector;
    switch (detectorType) {
        case FeatureDetectorType::FAST:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("FAST");
            break;
        case FeatureDetectorType::STAR:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("STAR");
            break;
        case FeatureDetectorType::SIFT:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
            break;
        case FeatureDetectorType::SURF:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
            break;
        case FeatureDetectorType::ORB:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("ORB");
            break;
        case FeatureDetectorType::BRISK:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("BRISK");
            break;
        case FeatureDetectorType::MSER:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("MSER");
            break;
        default:
            detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
            break;
    }
    detector->detect(image1, _keypoints1);
    detector->detect(image2, _keypoints2);

    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor;
    switch (extractorType) {
        case DescriptorExtractorType::SIFT:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");
            break;
        case DescriptorExtractorType::SURF:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
            break;
        case DescriptorExtractorType::BRIEF:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("BRIEF");
            break;
        case DescriptorExtractorType::BRISK:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("BRISK");
            break;
        case DescriptorExtractorType::ORB:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("ORB");
            break;
        case DescriptorExtractorType::FREAK:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("FREAK");
            break;
        default:
            extractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");
            break;
    }
    extractor->compute(image1, _keypoints1, _descriptors1);
    extractor->compute(image2, _keypoints2, _descriptors2);

    if (!_descriptors1.empty() && !_descriptors2.empty()) {
        switch (matcherType) {
            case DescriptorMatcherType::BRUTE_FORCE:
                if (extractorType == DescriptorExtractorType::ORB || extractorType == DescriptorExtractorType::BRISK || extractorType == DescriptorExtractorType::BRIEF) {
                    _matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce-Hamming"); 
                } else {
                    _matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
                }
                break;
            case DescriptorMatcherType::FLANN:
                _matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
                break;
            default:
                _matcher = cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
                break;
        }

        _matcher->knnMatch(_descriptors1, _descriptors2, _matches, 2);
        if (_matches.size() > 0) {
            _matchesMask = std::vector<bool>(_matches.size(), true);
            _matched = true;
        } else {
            std::cout << "No matching features could be found." << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        _matched = false;
        std::cout << "No descriptors could be extracted." << std::endl;
    }
}

void KeypointMatcher::homographyFilterMatches(OutlierFilter method) {
    if (!_matched) {
        std::cout << "Matching was not yet executed or no matches have been found." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> matchingPoints1, matchingPoints2;
    matchingPoints1.reserve(_matches.size());
    matchingPoints2.reserve(_matches.size());
    std::vector<int> indices;
    indices.reserve(_matches.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < _matchesMask.size(); ++i) {
        if (_matchesMask[i] == true) {
            matchingPoints1.push_back(_keypoints1[_matches[i][0].queryIdx].pt);
            matchingPoints2.push_back(_keypoints2[_matches[i][0].trainIdx].pt);
            indices.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    int meth;
    if (method == OutlierFilter::RANSAC) meth = cv::RANSAC; else meth = cv::LMEDS;
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::findHomography(matchingPoints1, matchingPoints2, meth, 3, mask);
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.rows; ++i) {
        _matchesMask[indices[i]] = _matchesMask[indices[i]] && (mask.at<uchar>(i, 0) == 1);
    }
}
```

And from the main:

```
cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread("G:/Desktop/thresholded1.png");
cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread("G:/Desktop/thresholded2.png");
hb::KeypointMatcher matcher;
matcher.computeMatches(image1, image2, hb::KeypointMatcher::FeatureDetectorType::SIFT, hb::KeypointMatcher::DescriptorExtractorType::SIFT);
matcher.homographyFilterMatches();
```

Here is another case where sift works well:

[image]

This is two times the same image but slightly rotated and scaled.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug.. so I maybe if you post your code I can help. In any case, an easy thing to try is to limit the homography a little bit. In the first example you are getting a homography with that maps all points to a very small area. These homographies have small singular values and can be easily ruled out.

Comment: I added the code for the matching and the homography filtering. I also added another example where the SIFT works. There it's just two times the same image rotated and scaled. I am using the OpenCV function `findHomography()` with the RANSAC filtering, so I don't have much influence on that.

Comment: Intuitively I'd say, SIFT is not particularly well suited for binary images. But I might be intuitively wrong.

Comment: Judging by the few examples attached, it seems like your images undergo a similarity transformation rather than perspective. Therefore, consider using OpenCV's [estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=estimaterigidtransform) instead which does the feature matching internally. Another thing to try is to plot the matches *without* `findHomography` to be able to better debug the cause.

Comment: The gradient information in binary image is so less than in grayscale image.